# Confused returning references

Tags: c++

I have these two functions

```
int FEL::enqueue(Event& new_event){
     getting a reference of an event and add it to an Event array, defined as "Event *event_list"
}

Event FEL::dequeue(){
    Event old_root = event_list[0];
    event_list[0] = event_list[--event_index];
    resort_heap(0);
    return old_root;
}
```

It works great but I want to modify this for a better performance in dequeue function.
Since dequeue function returns Event, I figured it might be better if I just return a reference of the event instead of the whole event structure.

How do I change the return type of the dequeue function to return a reference of an event? 
I think I can do something like this to return a pointer but how do I return a reference (&) of the event?

```
Event* FEL::dequeue(){
    Event *old_root = &event_list[0];
    event_list[0] = event_list[--event_index];
    resort_heap(0);
    return old_root;
}
```

Comment: Well, you can't return a reference to something that you overwrite or remove. How is that supposed to work? Returning a copy seems like the most sensible approach. Or just use a standard library container.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a pointer will not work, since you're modifying `event_list[0]` and `old_root` is a pointer to that object, so it will point to the new value instead of the old value. As for returning a reference, you can't either, because the returned value must be a member of the class (or an element of a member of a class and so on), and if you did that, you would get the new value, not the old.

If you want to return the old value, your only solution is to return by value. It may not be as bad as you think, though. Most compilers can apply *return value optimization*, meaning that the object isn't copied. Moreover, if the object contains any allocated storage, it can benefit from move semantics on C++11.

**Edit:** Sorry, there is of course another way to do this.

```
void FEL::dequeue(Event *old){
    *old = event_list[0];
    event_list[0] = event_list[--event_index];
    resort_heap(0);
}
```

Note that this may be a premature optimization gone wrong due to the aforementioned optimizations.